# Sharepoint Online Search error with CSOM 'No User or App Context found'

Tags: azure, rest, sharepoint, permissions, token

I try to make a basic search using Sharepoint REST API, but I run into this error:
[view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDcX7.png)

The authorization is done by a token created using ClientId and ClientSecret values.

The permission of Azure App are:

---

- AllSites.Read
- AllSites.Manage
- Sites.Read.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All
- Sites.Search.All
- Sites.Selected
- User.Read.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

Also the application is registered with permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepointDomain.com/sites/mySite"
                          Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I´ve tried with this with no luck:

> 

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
```

If I use SharePointOnlineCredentials for authentification, the search is working, but unfortunately we can use this anymore in .Net 6.0

```
private static void SearchFile(string folderPath, string searchText)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                };

                //clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativePath);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
                keywordQuery.QueryText = searchText;
                SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
                ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

---

Comment: 1st of all, sharepoint addins are registered throught azure ACS, not azure AD. 2nd, if you are in an external azure AD app, you can't call sharepoint REST query using clientid/client secret. You must use certificate authentication in your azure app

Comment: I can do all other operations (get file, get folder, add folder etc) with the token generated based on ClientID/ClientSecret; only the searching is not working.

Comment: You have to give more details. The screenshot looks like you opened the search REST query from your browser. Can you post the relevant code, especially how to create the context and how you execute your request ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the source code. Indeed, the screenshot is done when I'm testing this with Postman, the error is the same if I call https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/_api/search/query?querytext='test'

Comment: Why are you overriding the authorization header ? how do you obtain the access token ?

Comment: It need a type of authentification (with token or credentials). The token is the result of a HTTP Post with the following body: $"resource={resource}&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={sharePointSettings.ClientID}@{sharePointSettings.TenantID}&client_secret={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sharePointSettings.ClientSecret)}";

Comment: @Irina have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft explain in the [Using add-in only / app-only permissions with search queries in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/vesku/using-add-in-only-app-only-permissions-with-search-queries-in-sharepoint-online) article that the search requires this permission :

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
     <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/tenant"
                           Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

It's quite a high level privilege requirements. I don't know if you can switch to user context request, but I think it would be preferable.

Comment: I've tried <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" /> that seems that run a query as a user, but the error is the same.